# p:overlayPanel does not show the content

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

```
<h:form>
    <p:dialog>
        <p:outputPanel>
            <p:panelGrid>
                <p:row>
                    <p:column>
                        <p:commandLink value="link" id="myLink"/>
                        <p:overlayPanel  id="overPanel" for="myLink" >
                            <p:outputLabel id="linkPanel" value="#{bean.value}"/>
                        </p:overlayPanel>
                    </p:column>
                </p:row>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

In the above snippet overlay panel does not show the content, only an empty panel shown, but if I replace the value with the hardcoded one like `value="test"`, I can see the content in the overlay panel, when I inspect the page with firebug I can see the content is not placed inside the div of overlay panel. Can someone help on this?

Comment: That depends upon how you set the value to a corresponding property in the corresponding managed bean. Check out, if it is really set with a correct value and in a correct period of time.

Comment: The values are set correctly, even I can see the value in firebug, the issue is not set inside the div of overlay panel

Comment: Uh! Why are you using a `<p:outputLabel>` unnecessarily? Instead, an `<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}"/>` should be sufficient.

Comment: I want to show the output content in a pop-up that's the reason I used overlaypanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your `p:overlayPanel` Lazy Load might solve the problem. You can achive it by using `dynamic="true"` on your `p:overlayPanel`.

This technique makes your  `p:overlayPanel`'s contents to not render on page load itself, render just before `p:overlayPanel` is shown.

One more way is to update your `p:outputLabel` from the `p:commandLink`.

Yet another way is to use the client side js function `loadContents()` on your `p:overlayPanel`'s widgetwar. Since you are keeping your overlay inside datatable this might not be a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using toString() like this :

```
<p:outputLabel id="linkPanel" value="#{bean.value.toString()}" />
```

i had the same error this solved it. And try to make sure you have the method toString overriden inside your bean .

Comment: But the value is already in a string, so converting a string to string really maters